# Setting up wireless hot spot on Lion, DHCP issues

Tags: macos, network, airport

I have Lion communicating via wire to old (spaceship) AEBS which is currently DHCP serving an IP address to the Lion. The AEBS plugged in via wire to the cable modem.

I want to set up internet sharing on the Lion using its 801.11n wireless connection.

I set up the Lion and get the grey up-arrow, no problem. Except as soon as it launches, then the Lion loses internet access. I assume this is because I have defacto created two DHCP servers.

So want I think will solve it is to stop the Lion from requesting an address from AEBS. E.g. manually assign it to 10.0.1.2.

I must be doing something dumb here though, because once I set to a manual IP address then the AEBS is refusing to let me access the internet. What settings should be on it (subnet masks, etc). I'd still like the AEBS to provide DNS, etc.

I have not purchase the OS X Server software but am happy to do so if needed.

Comment: Ok, well, apparently posting here solved the problem!! After that I tried to repeat the exercise with a little more care. Seems like I needed to do the extra step of releasing the DHCP assigned value of 10.0.1.2 before then doing the manual assign of 10.0.1.2

Comment: Next step:: firewalls. I tried to turn on Lion Firewall but, not unreasonably, it is greyed-out once you turn on internet sharing. So that means the only thing between me and the open internet is the AEBS. I read (please someone confirm) that NAT is on by default and the only port that is open is 80. Is there an easy way to confirm this? Should I be worried that I dont have a more powerful wall?

Comment: Go to your security and privacy settings and check it there.

Comment: I missed that! when and where and why do you turn on the internet sharing ?

Comment: Hm, so it seems like I am not out of the woods. The big picture:: Comcast says that splitting internet and TV in the living room is really bad, instead I should split in the attic. Fine. So in the attic I send them down to cable-modem in the office. Hook office up to old AEBS as router and hence to Lion which is now sharing internet wirelessly throughout the house. Then I take the other line from the attic and bring downstairs to cable box and from their to TV and, somewhat surprisingly, the  TV signal is indeed a bit better. Except I want AppleTV/Hulu/Netflix/etc too. So now I need to extend.

Comment: Which gets me to my next problem. In addition to old AEBS, I also have a new Airport Extreme 801.11n. So I want it to be downstairs, picking up the Wifi and then sending data to the HDTV/BluRay/etc. The Lion DHCP is sending an IP address to the AE, but it doesn't seem completely happy about forwarding.

Comment: Interesting reading (mostly monologue) :)

Comment: Console reading just as fascinating :-)                  I'm getting a lot of inet_set_autoaddr(en1, 1) failed, Resource busy(16); AirPort_Brcm43xx::getKey_RSC resquesting RSC's for indices 1 and 2; and wlc_ioctl returning zero

Comment: almost there !!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got it. Upgrading Extreme to 7.6.3 might have been the root cause, but in addition I set up two wireless nets rather than one. Here is the set-up

CableModem -> Airport(Spaceship) running 11g serving DHCP values above 10.0.1.100 but accepting 10.0.1.xx with subnet mask. 11g given an obscure (private) name for the wireless account.

Spaceship -> Mac Mini via wire. Mac Mini with fixed address of 10.0.1.2

Mac Mini running internet sharing on 11n. Every wireless in the house able to connect via 11n. The 11n given a different (public) name for the wireless account and that's the wireless I tell friends visiting house.

AirportExtreme -> running in bridge mode, connecting via WDS to Spaceship, reading the 11g. Output on wire from the Extreme going to BoxWithNoWireless

BoxWithNoWireless requests DHCP and gets served an IP address from the Extreme.

Once all in place I did need to reboot the cable-modem too. Not sure why.

Not as clean as running a single 11n everywhere, however, and the BoxWithNoWireless is going to be running Netflix, etc, so I was really hoping to get 11n. But this at least gets me up-and-running.